# how to create table with formulas to calculate data in second table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a ProductTable with 1000 products. For example below is just 7 products. The data for products 1-5 is imported to the table from sources by script. I'll use this data to calculate data for other products.

Then I have a second table with formulas to calculate data for products in the first table. There will be a lot of product and every of them will have a certain formula. For example below are 2 products.
This table doesn't use digits but links to first table. Numbers are productsID from first table.

Third table is for a clear understanding and shows how calculations should be done. It is not a desired result. Result will be result of these calculations. (For ProductID6 and year1999 the result should be 3; for productID6 and year2001 result is 1.75, etc.)

[image: 1]

How can I write a stored procedure to catch these formulas fork. So basically I want to make a way to store formulas for calculating products. And, if needed, be able to change formula and recalculate the result.

Would be happy to hear your ideas.

Comment: So each product has 5 input rows and two output rows?

Comment: No. There are more than 1000 products. But some of them are inserted by script and others are calculated from the first ones. So I want to store formulas to calculate these products.

Comment: and each product is unique but every year it is changing. Imagine prices for food: it will be prices for milk, bread, beer, cheese and coffee.

Comment: Is a .NET solution acceptable. A stored procedure just does not have the tools to parse a formula.  Even with CLR not sure you would get there as CLR is still row based.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498(v=VS.80).aspx    I mean a .NET solution where you read the data into a .NET collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a number of ways to go with this, but I would try creating a scaler function that takes the year and ProductID as arguments and returns a single mapped formula.

```
-- Assumption is a Product table structured like this: Product(ProductID INT, [1999] INT, [2000] INT, [2001] INT);
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MapFn(@Y INT, @ProductID INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @A VARCHAR(10), @B VARCHAR(10), @C VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE @pvt TABLE(ProductID INT, Yr INT, Qty VARCHAR(10));
    DECLARE @f VARCHAR(80);

    INSERT @pvt
    SELECT ProductID, Yr, Qty
    FROM (
        SELECT ProductID, [1999], [2000], [2001]
        FROM dbo.Product) p
    UNPIVOT (
        Qty FOR Yr IN ([1999], [2000], [2001])
    ) AS u
    WHERE Yr = @Y;

    SELECT @f = formula FROM dbo.Formula WHERE ProductID = @ProductID
    SELECT @A = p.Qty + '.0' FROM @pvt p JOIN dbo.Formula f ON f.ProductID = @ProductID AND f.A = p.ProductID;
    SELECT @B = p.Qty + '.0' FROM @pvt p JOIN dbo.Formula f ON f.ProductID = @ProductID AND f.B = p.ProductID;
    SELECT @C = p.Qty + '.0' FROM @pvt p JOIN dbo.Formula f ON f.ProductID = @ProductID AND f.C = p.ProductID;

    RETURN REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@f,'A', ISNULL(CAST(@A AS VARCHAR(50)), '')), 'B', ISNULL(CAST(@B AS VARCHAR(50)), '')), 'C', ISNULL(CAST(@C AS VARCHAR(50)), ''));
END
GO
```

The function is brittle with the fixed year list in the UNPIVOT, but you can work around that by adding more years to the list.

**Usage Example**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Product(ProductID INT, [1999] INT, [2000] INT, [2001] INT);
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Formula(ProductID INT, formula VARCHAR(80), [A] INT, [B] INT, [C] INT);
GO

INSERT dbo.Product values(1,10,20,30)
, (2,15,25,35)
, (3,5,15,20)
, (4,4,8,12)
, (5,6,12,18)
, (6,NULL,NULL,NULL)
, (7,NULL,NULL,NULL);

INSERT dbo.Formula VALUES(6,'A/B',2,3,NULL)
, (7,'A/(B+C)',5,3,1);
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MapFn(@Y INT, @ProductID INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @A VARCHAR(10), @B VARCHAR(10), @C VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE @pvt TABLE(ProductID INT, Yr INT, Qty VARCHAR(10));
    DECLARE @f VARCHAR(80);

    INSERT @pvt
    SELECT ProductID, Yr, Qty
    FROM (
        SELECT ProductID, [1999], [2000], [2001]
        FROM dbo.Product) p
    UNPIVOT (
        Qty FOR Yr IN ([1999], [2000], [2001])
    ) AS u
    WHERE Yr = @Y;

    SELECT @f = formula FROM dbo.Formula WHERE ProductID = @ProductID
    SELECT @A = p.Qty + '.0' FROM @pvt p JOIN dbo.Formula f ON f.ProductID = @ProductID AND f.A = p.ProductID;
    SELECT @B = p.Qty + '.0' FROM @pvt p JOIN dbo.Formula f ON f.ProductID = @ProductID AND f.B = p.ProductID;
    SELECT @C = p.Qty + '.0' FROM @pvt p JOIN dbo.Formula f ON f.ProductID = @ProductID AND f.C = p.ProductID;

    RETURN REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@f,'A', ISNULL(CAST(@A AS VARCHAR(50)), '')), 'B', ISNULL(CAST(@B AS VARCHAR(50)), '')), 'C', ISNULL(CAST(@C AS VARCHAR(50)), ''));
END
GO

-- Cursor loop to evaluate formulas
DECLARE @ProductID INT;
DECLARE @fa NVARCHAR(80);
DECLARE @fb NVARCHAR(80);
DECLARE @fc NVARCHAR(80);
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(160);
DECLARE @A DECIMAL(10,2), @B DECIMAL(10,2), @C DECIMAL(10,2)
DECLARE @resultSet TABLE(ProductID INT, [1999] DECIMAL(10,2), [2000] DECIMAL(10,2), [2001] DECIMAL(10,2));
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT f.ProductID
    , [1999] = dbo.MapFn(1999,f.ProductID)
    , [2000] = dbo.MapFn(2000,f.ProductID)
    , [2001] = dbo.MapFn(2001,f.ProductID)
    FROM dbo.Formula f;
OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @ProductID, @fa, @fb, @fc;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    -- 1999
    SET @sql = N'SELECT @out = '+@fa;
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @params = N'@out DECIMAL(10,2) OUTPUT', @out = @A OUTPUT;

    -- 2000
    SET @sql = N'SELECT @out = '+@fb;
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @params = N'@out DECIMAL(10,2) OUTPUT', @out = @B OUTPUT;

    -- 2001
    SET @sql = N'SELECT @out = '+@fc;
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @params = N'@out DECIMAL(10,2) OUTPUT', @out = @C OUTPUT;

    INSERT @resultSet VALUES(@ProductID, @A, @B, @C);
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @ProductID, @fa, @fb, @fc;
END
SELECT * FROM @resultSet;
CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;
```

**Result**

```
ProductID   1999    2000    2001
6           3.00    1.67    1.75
7           0.40    0.34    0.36
```

Comment: thanks for answer. please pay attention - Third table is for a clear understanding and shows only how calculations should be done. It is not a desired result. Result will be result of these calculations. (For ProductID6 and year1999 the result should be 3; for productID6 and year2001 result is 1.75, etc.)

Comment: In that case a cursor will be needed to execute the formulas in the result table, invoking a call to sp_executesql with an output parameter. I'll explore that possibility later today when I return from work.

Comment: Yeah I also was thinking about cursor. Will wait for your answer John.

Comment: dbo.MapFn updated to add a .0 after each quantity, and the usage example is updated to use the cursor loop I had in mind.

Comment: hi John, I am trying to use your code for my system. Can you please add some comments to code, for better understanding how it works?

Comment: or maybe I should describe my situation in details because what is described in task is pretty much a small model of what I have in real ...

Comment: Somehow this place returns an error:  


'   SELECT ProductID, Yr, Qty
    FROM (
        SELECT ProductID, [1999], [2000], [2001]
        FROM dbo.Product) p
    UNPIVOT (
        Qty FOR Yr IN ([1999], [2000], [2001])
    ) AS u
    WHERE Yr = @Y; '

INVALID column name

Comment: maybe you could send me your contact email? my address is in my profile

Comment: I'll need more specific info about your dbo.Product structure vs. my example. Email: maybe it's my browser, but I'm not seeing an email address in your profile.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733834/how-to-create-table-with-formulas-and-use-them-to-calculate-data2?lq=1) here I described my real situation ... and my email is my profile name Almazini at google dot com.